# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore dont have method IsOptional() for PropertyBuilder

Tags: asp.net-core, mapping, entity-framework-core

I try transfer my solution from .Net Framowork to .Net Core.When I did mapping and I dint found method IsOptional() for PropertyBuilder:

.Net Framowork:

```
    public class PictureMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PictureExt>
{
    public PictureMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Picture");
        this.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        this.Property(p => p.SeoFilename).HasMaxLength(300);
        this.Property(p => p.ExternalUrl).IsOptional();
    }
}
```

and its work , but use EntityFrameworkCore:[look in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQAQl.png)

where I might found IsOptional()?

Answer (score 2):

There is not `IsOptional` in EntityFrameworkCore but there is `IsRequired` to do the oposite. By default field are nullable if the C# type is nullable.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect with IsRequired(false).  This will override annotations like [Required] so be careful.  On another thread, it was pointed out that annotations that affect EF models or make no sense [Display...] should not be part of the EF model.  Move them to a ViewModel or DTO object.